# How to apply keras image preprocessing in R when using a pre-trained model

Tags: r, keras

I am trying to train a model to identify what kind of fruits are there in a picture. They can be multi-labelled (e.g. banana and apple in same image). The 100 rows of data (fruit) are stored in a csv file with the first few rows looking like this :

```
Key Banana Apple Orange img_path
1 0 0 1 data/121.jpg
2 0 1 1 data/228.jpg
3 1 0 1 data/368.jpg
...
```

The approach that I am going to do is to extract features with a pre-trained model (InceptionV3) before using them to train my keras model. The code below works fine and i am able to get what i wanted to train my model later on.

```
fruit_model <- application_inception_v3(weights = 'imagenet', include_top = F,
                            input_shape = c(150, 150, 3))
freeze_weights(fruit_model)
extract_features <- function(img_path) {
   img <- image_load(img_path, target_size = c(150,150))
   x <- image_to_array(img)
   x <- array_reshape(x, c(1, dim(x)))
   x <- inception_v3_preprocess_input(x)

   output <- predict(fruit_model, x)
   output

 }

all_fruit_features <- array(data = 0.1, dim = c(nrow(fruit), 3, 3, 2048))

for (i in 1:nrow(fruit)) {
 all_fruit_features[i, , , ] <- extract_features(fruit$img_path[i])
}
# The all_fruit_features is an array with dim = (100,3,3,2048) which is the numpy array (x) that i use when fitting my model later on
```

However, since i only have 100 rows of data (which is far too little to train a deep learning model), i would want to have more data through the use of keras image processing. I hope to generate more images with same image by applying orientation change ( 1 image become 5 image). I tried something like this below but when i fit my model with the new numpy array , i have lower accuracy and so i think i am doing something wrong below with my code. I am not sure what is it.

```
datagen = image_data_generator(
  rotation_range=20,
  width_shift_range=0.2,
  height_shift_range=0.2,
  horizontal_flip=T)

extract_features <- function(img_path) {
  img <- image_load(img_path, target_size = c(150,150))
  x <- image_to_array(img)
  x <- array_reshape(x, c(1, dim(x)))
  x <- inception_v3_preprocess_input(x)
  output <-predict_generator(fruit_model, flow_images_from_data(x , generator=datagen) ,steps = 10)
  output 
}

all_fruit_features <- array(data = 0.1, dim = c(nrow(fruit)*10, 3, 3, 2048))

for (i in 1:nrow(fruit)) {
  for (j in 1:10){
    lol <- extract_features(fruit$img_path[i])
    all_fruit_features[j+(i-1)*10, , , ] <- array_reshape(lol[j], c(1, 
dim(lol[j])))
  }
}
```

The all_fruit_features here is an array with dim = (1000,3,3,2048) which is what i wanted but when i run it with my model later on, it looks off with lower accuracy and i am not sure what is wrong. Please help thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the rotation range? Also different "fake" images, could help alleviate overfit, just add different random transformations, example:

`train_datagen = image_data_generator(
  rotation_range = 40,
  width_shift_range = 0.2,
  height_shift_range = 0.2,
  shear_range = 0.2,
  zoom_range = 0.2,
  horizontal_flip = TRUE,
  fill_mode = "nearest"
)`

Comment: Hi , thanks for replying. I am concerned whether the code is running correctly i.e. it is actually generating images with different transformation which is the reason why my model is not working well. I am new to keras and not sure if i am writing the code correctly. Working around with the transformation might improve my model subsequently but that is not my concern for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is solved. The argument for predict_generator is not working properly in the above code. Appended is the updated code.

```
extract_features <- function(img_path) {
  img <- image_load(img_path, target_size = c(150,150))
  x <- image_to_array(img)
  x <- array_reshape(x, c(1, dim(x)))
  x <- inception_v3_preprocess_input(x)
  output <- predict_generator(fruit_model,flow_images_from_data(x,generator = 
datagen,save_to_dir = 'image_folder',save_format = 'png'),steps=10)
  output
}
```